# Canvas: Text width is not equal to the summary of the widths of its characters

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, text

In most cases, they are the same. But I found this special case, it is different when I change the order of characters.

```
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
const tw = text => ctx.measureText(text).width;

tw('Tr') - tw('T') - tw('r') // -0.3662109375
tw('rT') - tw('T') - tw('r') // 0
```

Can anyone tell me the rules of this behavior? Thank you!

Comment: Non-fixed length fonts will have different results on rendering. Since you decided to for whatever reason break it all into "words".

Comment: @mardubbles I want to measure the text width based on char widths. It has better performant in my case as I can cache char widths.

Comment: Ok, but in your "formulas" you never factor in the width of a "white space" which varies on non-fixed width fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), which is how some characters will be more or less close to their neighbors.
This will depend on the font used, and the characters shown.

Chrome recently added support for a `.fontKerning` property that we can use to disable this,

```js
if ("fontKerning" in CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype) {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.font = "30px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillText("AV", 0, 30);
  console.log("with kerning", ctx.measureText("AV").width);
  ctx.fontKerning = "none";
  console.log("without kerning", ctx.measureText("AV").width);
  ctx.fillText("AV", 0, 60);
  console.log("sum of chars", ctx.measureText("A").width + ctx.measureText("V").width);
}
else {
  console.log("your browser doesn't support setting fontKerning");
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

and you could use mono-space fonts to avoid it, but that would still not be bullet proof because even then some glyphs just can't be measured as you did.

So the best is to measure the full text that you want to measure.